# Attention File you are trying to upload exceeds maximum file size limit

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When I try to upload logo image I got this error 
Attention
File you are trying to upload exceeds maximum file size limit.

Answer (score 1):

Open the your php.ini file and search this two content

> upload_max_filesize
>
> post_max_size

And increase the two content size Ex:-

upload_max_filesize = 2000M

post_max_size = 2100M

And finally restart the your Apache and mysql

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Thankyou....It works

Comment: Please accept answer so this answer helpful another community